# combined report of multimodule gradle sonar build

Tags: gradle, multi-module, sonar-runner

I have a multimodule gradle project for which I get an index.html generated for each module as sonar runs. I need a combined index.html report of all the modules so that I can see the report in one single file instead of checking index.html of each module. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Which report are you referring to? This is likely to be considered an internal Sonar thing; the official output of Sonar is what you see in its web application.

Comment: I am talking about the junit report which gets generated for every module in the build/tests folder and has details of test cases being passed and failed. But I donot get any overall junit report.            My requirement is to send an overall sonar code coverage report via an email either through jenkins or command line...Sonar pdf report plugin does not seem to be working with gradle...

Comment: You can't produce such reports via the `sonar(-runner)` plugin. You'll have to use the specific plugin for the required tool/report, such as the `jacoco` plugin for code coverage reports (which isn't the same as test reports). The `jacoco` plugin also supports aggregation of coverage reports. For details, see the [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html) and the [Gradle Build Language Reference](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/index.html).